# Error installing pymc on debian sid

Tags: python-3.x, installation, lapack, pymc, pymc3

I have installed gfortran but `sudo pip3 install pymc` fails:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lapack/double/dpotrs.f'. Skipping file "lapack/double/dpotrs.
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lapack/double/dpotrf.f'. Skipping file "lapack/double/dpotrf.
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lapack/double/dpotf2.f'. Skipping file "lapack/double/dpotf2.
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lapack/double/ilaenv.f'. Skipping file "lapack/double/ilaenv.
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lapack/double/dlamch.f'. Skipping file "lapack/double/dlamch.
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lapack/double/ilaver.f'. Skipping file "lapack/double/ilaver.
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lapack/double/ieeeck.f'. Skipping file "lapack/double/ieeeck.
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lapack/double/iparmq.f'. Skipping file "lapack/double/iparmq.
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lapack/double/dpotrs.f'. Skipping file "lapack/double/dpotrs.
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lapack/double/dpotrf.f'. Skipping file "lapack/double/dpotrf.
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lapack/double/dpotf2.f'. Skipping file "lapack/double/dpotf2.
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lapack/double/ilaenv.f'. Skipping file "lapack/double/ilaenv.
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lapack/double/dlamch.f'. Skipping file "lapack/double/dlamch.
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lapack/double/ilaver.f'. Skipping file "lapack/double/ilaver.
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lapack/double/ieeeck.f'. Skipping file "lapack/double/ieeeck.f".
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lapack/double/iparmq.f'. Skipping file "lapack/double/iparmq.f".

error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lapack/double/dpotrs.f'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-hmfp8b5m/pymc/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-zyseyo76-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-hmfp8b5m/pymc
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out, I was missing the `liblapack-dev` package:

```
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev
```